# is Guidewire ending support for self-managed systems in next few years?

Tags: guidewire

Is guidwire claimceter v10 ending support for self-managed systems in next few years ? Do they have a mandate to move to cloud ? Any document available on public platform ? It will take some time to get response from the source - so trying here.

Answer (score 2):

All answers here (even from Guidewire employees) would be pure speculation. Guidewire still has customers using the self-managed versions and updates to the self-managed versions are published by Guidewire almost as frequently as the Cloud versions.

Guidewire does promote the Cloud versions more heavily than self-managed and encourages self-managed customers to migrate to Cloud instead of upgrading to the latest self-managed version. I would speculate that Guidewire will eventually end support for self-managed, but this will be be many years in the future and probably only when most of the self-managed customers have migrated to the Cloud.

This is just an opinion and I could very well be wrong about any of the above statements.